# Override function inside function using custom function defined just beforehand

Tags: python

I know the title is very confusing but essentially here is what I am trying to do:

```
def foo():
    bar(name)

def evaluate_foo(name_table):
    def bar(name, lookup_table=name_table):
        print(name + "'s last name is " + lookup_table[name])
    foo()
```

Basically, if I know that `foo` is going to make a call to `bar`, can I replace `bar` with my own function right before calling foo?

I am trying to provide a lookup table to bar, but the lookup table is generated inside of `evaluate_foo`. It's also important to me that someone using the function `bar` doesn't need to know about the lookup table that is being used by bar within it.

Comment: `bar` is local to `evaluate_foo`. `foo` cannot see it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you please make it more clear what it is you're trying to do.
p.s. You can't access bar from foo

Comment: Python has lexical scoping. It sounds like you want [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) for this to work.

Comment: @Coldspeed I have updated the example to be a bit clearer about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pass your function to `foo` to be executed. For instance you could do:

```
def foo(f):
    f()

def evaluate_foo(some_param):   
    baz = some_param.get_special_number()
    def bar(bar_param=baz):
        print("Bar's result is " + str(baz))
    foo(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because `foo()` will lookup the function referred to by `bar` in the namespace it's defined in, not the namespace it's called in.

This sort of situation is what object inheritance is for, instead of having function `foo()` you should redesign it to be object `whatever` with method `whatever.foo()` and `whatever.bar()`. Then you can subclass `whatever` and write a new method `bar()` that `foo()` will find because it's defined in the class namespace.

Presumably you want to do this because you don't control `foo()` and so you can't convert it from a function into a method. In that case you can achieve this by monkey-patching `bar()` in the same namespace where `foo()` is defined, but that's some deep dark voodoo that is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to override a function definition globally. The following is not pretty, but it works (with some caveats below):

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

def baz():
    print("baz")
    foo()

def bar():
    def local_foo():
        print("local foo")

    global foo
    foo = local_foo

    baz()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar()
```

The output is

```
baz
local foo
```

**So, the caveats:**

You can only do this for global functions, unless you want to jump through even more hoops.

The second point is that, unless you're just doing this for fun or are desperate, you should use other methods (as described by others) to achieve the same effect. E.g. some kind of design pattern.